# Rails: find if a value exists inside a array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table named discounts with an array column named user_id.

```
 create_table "discounts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "amount"
 t.string "name"
 t.string "from"
 t.string "to"
 t.integer "user_id", default: [], array: true
```

I want to search the entire table of discounts and find only the rows that have a user_id(`current_user.id`).

Any ideas how to implant this search?

Comment: relational approach would have made more sense I think

Comment: Take a look at [The `has_and_belongs_to_many` Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Discount.where(":user_id = ANY(user_id)", user_id: current_user.id)
```

This should do it for you. I assume that `user_id` is an array field in a postgres database.

I'd recommend that you also index `user_id` to be more performant. To create an index for your array column, you must choose between GiST and GIN as strategies. The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) covers the options nicely, but the distilled version is that GIN lookups are much (3x) faster, but take longer (10x) to build. If your data is read far more often than it is written, go for GIN.

Your migration could be something like:

```
create_table "discounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "amount"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "from"
  t.string "to"
  t.integer "user_id", default: [], array: true
end

add_index  :discounts, :user_id, using: 'gin'
```

Comment: @Dev I also added a recommendation to add an index to your data to make it more performant. Could you mark the answer as correct? that helps to maintain the quality of the answers at Stackoverflow.